# ReSharper Member Rename Across Assemblies

Tags: resharper, rename

I've been a ReSharper user for close to a year and cant imagine working w/o it. But one thing I'm trying to get it to do but cant find options to is when you rename a property have it make the updates in other caller assemblies. It renames the member perfectly in the same project but caller projects aren't updated (all are loaded as part of the solution obviously).

Anyone know how to make it do just that? Thanks!

..Using latest version 6.x...

Comment: All accessible source code usages of the renamed symbol should be updated. If they're not, it's worth [reporting a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP#newissue=yes) with details, possibly including a sample solution to reproduce it.

Comment: It also has always worked for me.  Are those assemblies/projects loaded into your solution when you try to do a rename?  R# won't go out into the fail system to find files to rename.  If the projects are loaded and the source files are available and R# still isn't doing it, then file a bug.